# SQL Query: How to rearrange the output (Transpose?)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, transpose

I have a resultset from SQL Server like this:

```
Zone        M1      M2  M3  M4  M5  M6  M7
NORTH       6233    17743   2   6233    6717    7369    7369
SOUTH       12440   20017   7   8057    9724    13418   13418
WEST        33736   30532   5   2184    2056    1944    1944
EAST        3944    14584   2   728     953     970     970
CENTRAL     6233    3636    2   6233    6717    6825    6825
```

But I wanted it in the following fashion:

```
M       NORTH   SOUTH   WEST    EAST    CENTRAL
M1      6233    12440   33736   3944    6233
M2      17743   20017   30532   14584   3636
M3      2       7       5       2       2
M4      ....
```

How to do this?

Or else, how can I get it in this format:

```
Zone    M   Value
EAST    M1  6322
WEST    M1  27387
EAST    M2  2345
....
```

Comment: I think you're looking for the **[Pivot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)** operator

Comment: I tried PIVOT, but could not get this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do to get the result is a two-step process of implementing both the `UNPIVOT` and then the `PIVOT` functions.

The first step is to `UNPIVOT` the data, this takes your multiple columns `M1`, `M2`, etc and turns them into two columns with the value and the column name:

```
select zone, value, col
from data
unpivot
(
  value
  for col in ([M1], [M2], [M3], 
              [M4], [M5], [M6], [M7])
) unpiv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/16b8f/3)

Once you have performed the `UNPIVOT` then you can apply the `PIVOT` to the `Zone` column:

```
select *
from
(
  select zone, value, col
  from data
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in ([M1], [M2], [M3], 
                [M4], [M5], [M6], [M7])
  ) unpiv
) src
pivot
(
  sum(value)
  for zone in ([North], [South], [West], [East], [Central])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/16b8f/4)

Now if you do not have access to the `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT` function, then you can perform the same using a `UNION ALL` for the `UNPIVOT` and an aggregate function with a `CASE` to replicate the `PIVOT`:

```
select col,
  sum(case when zone='North' then value end) North,
  sum(case when zone='South' then value end) South,
  sum(case when zone='West' then value end) West,
  sum(case when zone='East' then value end) East,
  sum(case when zone='Central' then value end) Central
from
(
  select zone, M1 value, 'M1' col
  from data
  union all
  select zone, M2 value, 'M2' col
  from data
  union all
  select zone, M3 value, 'M3' col
  from data
  union all
  select zone, M4 value, 'M4' col
  from data
  union all
  select zone, M5 value, 'M5' col
  from data
  union all
  select zone, M6 value, 'M6' col
  from data
  union all
  select zone, M7 value, 'M7' col
  from data
) un
group by col
```

See [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5cebc/1)

Finally, if you had an unknown number of columns to either unpivot or pivot, then you could use a dynamic version of this:

```
DECLARE @colsUnpivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsPivot as  NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsUnpivot = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.name)
         from sys.columns as C
         where C.object_id = object_id('data') and
               C.name not in ('zone')
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT  distinct ',' 
                      + quotename(Zone)
                    from data
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query 
  = 'select *
     from
     (
        select zone, value, col
        from data
        unpivot
        (
          value
          for col in ('+ @colsunpivot +')
        ) u
      ) unpiv
      pivot
      (
        max(value)
        for zone in ('+ @colspivot +')
      ) p'

exec(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/16b8f/7)

All versions will produce the same result.

Result:

```
| COL | CENTRAL |  EAST | NORTH | SOUTH |  WEST |
-------------------------------------------------
|  M1 |    6233 |  3944 |  6233 | 12440 | 33736 |
|  M2 |    3636 | 14584 | 17743 | 20017 | 30532 |
|  M3 |       2 |     2 |     2 |     7 |     5 |
|  M4 |    6233 |   728 |  6233 |  8057 |  2184 |
|  M5 |    6717 |   953 |  6717 |  9724 |  2056 |
|  M6 |    6825 |   970 |  7369 | 13418 |  1944 |
|  M7 |    6825 |   970 |  7369 | 13418 |  1944 |
```

Comment: Pivot, unpivot, dynamic pivot and sql fiddle.  Why can I only upvote once!